# Transparent decompression of JavaScript Blob objects

Tags: javascript, http, blob

Modern browsers can handle deflated/gzip'd data sent by the web server. For instance, you can configure Apache to deliver gzip compressed HTML files if the browser supports it.

I'm trying to use this feature with [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)s.

I have a JavaScript program that creates a Blob from compressed data embedded into the JS file, then uses XMLHttpRequest to load the data from the generated `blob:` URL.

However, no matter what content type I specify when creating the Blob, for instance `application/octet-stream;deflate` or `application/octet-stream;gzip`, no decompression is applied by the browser. I tried several content types, but to no avail. The browser seems to ignore the encoding specified in the content type string.

Is it possible to load a`blob:` resource and have it automatically decompressed/inflated by the browser the same way as if loaded from `http:`, i.e. a web server?

Comment: How (and, notably, *Why*) are you embedding compressed data in a JS file?

Comment: How: In a base64 encoded string; Why: because it's one of the goals of the project I work on: a single file JS app that contains all required data. Both questions are not relevant.

Comment: But wouldn't [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.atob) take care of that? There is no `deflate` compression on it, is there? I mean, the data should be stored in the JS file encoded but *uncompressed*, and then the whole JS file should be served as compressed.

Comment: Just leaving the blobs uncompressed and compressing the whole file instead is a possibility, but that's not the point of the question.